# Is Kismet or another WIFI detector available for Android?

Tags: wi-fi

I'm a Sysadmin and would like to use my Android phone to detect Wifi networks at my workplace or at home.

Are there any tools like Kismet available for Android? I'm currently using a Samsung Intercept, which runs Android 2.1, but should receive Android 2.2 in the next month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there are several options.  Here are a couple of the more popular apps:

**[WiFiFoFum](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wififofum-wifi-scanner/com.dynamicallyloaded.wififofum)**

**AppBrain Description:**

> WiFiFoFum scans for 802.11 WiFi
>   networks and displays information
>   about each including: SSID, MAC, RSSI,
>   channel, and security. WiFiFoFum also
>   allows you to connect to networks you
>   find and log the location using the
>   GPS. KML logs can be emailed.

**[WiFi Scanner](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-scanner/gr.androiddev.WifiScanner)**

**AppBrain Description:**

> *No ads
>   *Option to connect added for open networks!!!
>   *Update comming soon
>
> A *free* WiFi Scanner for wireless
>   networks for Android.
>
> The WiFi signal is displayed in dBm
>   format!

If you are looking to sniff traffic try:

**[Shark for Root](http://www.appbrain.com/app/shark-for-root/lv.n3o.shark)**

**AppBrain Description:**

> Traffic sniffer, works on 3G and WiFi
>   (works on FroYo tethered mode too). To
>   open dump use WireShark or similar
>   software, for preview dump on phone
>   use Shark Reader. Based on tcpdump.
>   Please leave comments/send e-mail if
>   you have any problems/suggestions.

Answer (score 11):

I  use [Wifi Analyzer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-analyzer/com.farproc.wifi.analyzer), a free tool which gives a good range of Wifi detections. It will show you things like signal strengths, encryption levels, SSIDs on overlapping channels and a few other details.

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few apps capable of detecting wifi networks, however, [Pixie](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pixie-%28root%29/com.nbl.pixie) (Root only) is the only passive wifi detector that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3):

I have been running kismet on an original Droid with a 8 gig micro-SD card. 4 gig is fat32 for the phone pics , videos, and such,  the other 4 gig has Debian Squeeze running on it. Not to hard to setup.

Once the phone is rooted (must have) you can just use the freebee Linux installer from the market. Uncheck the loop box in settings, and change the device install to `/sd-ext`. Further at the bottom you will need to change the device to `mmcblk0p2`  or whatever your actual ext2 formatted Linux partition is.

You can type `mount` into terminal and it will list all the currently mounted directories and partitions. Make sure that `mmcblk0p2` or whatever is mounted to `/sd-ext`. The phones by default will mount the Linux partition on the `/sdcard` at boot, but do check and make sure.

I suggest connecting to Wi-Fi with fast inets for this, although your 3G with good bars will work just fine for this too.

Just follow the buttons 1) 2) 3):

- 1 is extract Debian to ****,
- 2 is install Debian to SD card,
- 3 is install script.

Be patient,  each step will take time. If you get errors check the log. Each device is a little different, but you will get it.

I have my kismet log dumps going to the fat32 partition on the `sdcard`. This way it is very easy to get the files you need for things like kismet log viewer or Backtrack.

Enjoy, I hope this sparks some fun for you :)

Comment: Sounds interesting, if you do ever write a full tutorial please let us know.